# remove specific element loaded from ajax

Tags: jquery

hello I have a item list div in which items are listed by ajax with no problem. without page refreshing, I want to remove specific div from the list by 2nd ajax call.

```html
<div id="itemList">
  <!-- these items are loaded by ajax -->
  <div id="item-1">Item 1</div>
  <div id="item-2">Item 2</div>
  <div id="item-3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

**1st ajax call**

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/path',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {list: important},
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
    $("#itemList").prepend(result.html);
  }
});
```

**2nd ajax call**

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/path',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {list: update},
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
    // try to remove the specific item. failed.
    $("#item-"+ result.id).remove();
  }
});
```

can anyone help me? thanks.

Comment: post server side code please

Comment: Are you sure that the success callback is called and the value of `result.id` is correct

Comment: can you display `result.id` in the console ? Are you sure the first ajax is finish when calling the second ?

Comment: check `$("#item-"+ result.id).remove();` here `result.id` must be correct

Comment: result.id is correct. I think the problem may be, 2nd ajax call, jquery cannot find the item div as they are loaded by 1st ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the list item is added via AJAX the DOM doesn't actually register it on page load. You'll need to target the parent element first like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/path',
  dataType: "json",
  data: {list: update},
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
      $('ul#itemList').find('#item-"+ result.id').remove();
  }
});
```